# Change timezone for .ics file Calendar

Tags: calendar, icalendar

I generated an .ics file and I want to change the timezone, in my current one doesn't matter what I change the time is +1. Basically the timezone is working but I have +1h.

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
PRODID:-//Google Inc//Google Calendar 70.9054//EN
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:Europe/London
BEGIN:STANDARD
TZNAME:MEZ
DTSTART:19700405T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=1SU;BYMONTH=4
TZOFFSETFROM:+1300
TZOFFSETTO:+1200
END:STANDARD
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
TZNAME:NZDT
DTSTART:19700928T030000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=-1SU;BYMONTH=9
TZOFFSETFROM:+1200
TZOFFSETTO:+1300
END:DAYLIGHT
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:20210920T120023Z-2fa80c3a-1@example.com
DTSTAMP:20210920T120023Z
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/London:20210922T164500Z
DTEND;TZID=Europe/London:20210923T164500Z
SEQUENCE:0
SUMMARY:Facetoface test 1
LOCATION:
DESCRIPTION:
CLASS:PRIVATE
TRANSP:OPAQUE
ORGANIZER;CN=Example Manager;LANGUAGE=en:MAILTO:manager@example.com
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a mashup of two ics DATE-TIME forms in there.  It should be one form or the other.

Either

```
DTSTART:20210922T164500Z
```

or

```
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/London:20210922T164500
```

not both at same time

See  FORM #2: DATE WITH UTC TIME and
FORM #3: DATE WITH LOCAL TIME AND TIME ZONE REFERENCE
in https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5545#section-3.3.5

Since London has daylight saving, there will be times when the UTC time is not the same as London time.